# Trying to create a datatable but I can't seem to make the rows as I want

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, datatables

I'll show the excel output in order to be easy to understand

[Excel output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlwl3.png)

The code is also very simple, how can I make the rows correct? I tried creating multiple datatables and merging them, but the merge is always vertical so I was getting the same output.

````
      dt.Columns.Add("Nomes", typeof(string));

      DataRow dr;

      for (int i = 0; i < surveyAnswers.Respostas.Count; i++) {


        if (i == 0) {

          dr = dt.NewRow();

          dr[0] = surveyAnswers.Respostas[i].quemRespondeu;
          dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        if (i > 0) {
          string nome = surveyAnswers.Respostas[i].quemRespondeu;


          if (nome != surveyAnswers.Respostas[i - 1].quemRespondeu) {
            dt.Rows.Add(nome);
          }
        }
      }

      

      for (int j = 0; j < surveyGroups.Count; j++) {

        string grupo = surveyGroups[j].SubTitulo;
        dt.Columns.Add(grupo, typeof(string));

        for (int i = 0; i < surveyAnswers.Respostas.Count; i++) {

          if (surveyAnswers.Respostas[i].QuestaoGrupo == j) {


            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[j] = surveyAnswers.Respostas[i].QuestaoPergunta;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);


          }


        }

      }


      Dictionary<string, string> header = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      header.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=questionario_resultados.csv");
      ResponseUtil.Write(context, DataTableToCSV.WriteToString(dt, true, false), "text/csv; charset=UTF-8", header); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new rows everytime you add a new column in the second for loop, when you created already the rows in the first one. Instead of creating a new row, you should modify the existing rows.

instead of this:

```
 dr = dt.NewRow();
 dr[j] = surveyAnswers.Respostas[i].QuestaoPergunta;
 dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Try with something like this:

```
dr[i][grupo] = surveyAnswers.Respostas[i].QuestaoPergunta;
```

I didn't test it.

Comment: Wow, you guys are amazing, I'll try your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know how do you get the excel file, I make a change to the excel to make it normal.

I create a winform app and used the datagridview to show the datatable.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\\test.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
        Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
        int usedrow = usedRange.Rows.Count;
        int usedcolumn = usedRange.Columns.Count;

        for (int i = 2; i <= usedcolumn; i++)
        {
            int row = worksheet.UsedRange.Columns[i, Type.Missing].Rows.Count;
            int firstrow = Firstusedrow(usedrow, i, worksheet);
            Excel.Range copyRange = worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[firstrow, i], worksheet.Cells[row, i]];
            Excel.Range insertRange = worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[2, i], worksheet.Cells[row, i]];
            insertRange.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, copyRange.Cut());
        }
       
       
        workbook.Save();
        workbook.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        DataTable table = READExcel("E:\\test.xlsx");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        MessageBox.Show("success");
    }
    public int Firstusedrow(int row,int column, Excel.Worksheet sheet)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < row; i++)
        {
            if ((sheet.Cells[i, column] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public DataTable READExcel(string path)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objXL = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objWB = null;
        objXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        objWB = objXL.Workbooks.Open(path);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objSHT = objWB.Worksheets[1];

        int rows = objSHT.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        int cols = objSHT.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        int noofrow = 1;

        for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
        {
            string colname = objSHT.Cells[1, c].Text;
            dt.Columns.Add(colname);
            noofrow = 2;
        }

        for (int r = noofrow; r <= rows; r++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
            {
                dr[c - 1] = objSHT.Cells[r, c].Text;
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        objWB.Close();
        objXL.Quit();
        return dt;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = READExcel("E:\\test.xlsx");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
```

Result；

[image]

Comment: Wow, you guys are amazing, I'll try your ideas!